# SQLite3 SELECT statement returning an object, not value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SQL query within a little bit of Python code, but instead of returning an object, it is returning an object. The data is in a table hence the currentRow() method on the tablewidget.

```
currentRow = tableWidget.currentRow()
alink = dbCursor.execute('''SELECT link from Headlines WHERE id = ?''', (currentRow,))
print alink, currentRow
```

It is returning `(sqlite3.cursor object at 0x03F3EF60)` but I am looking for the value. How can I return the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to call `dbCursor.fetchone()` to retrieve the results as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).